# Regarding amountOutMin not reverting a TX

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap, swaps

I'm trying to find a safe way to swap during token launches. Is there any?

I tried swapping 0.01 BNB (~$5 atm) for amountOutMin = 10 BUSD (via swapExactETHForTokens), but the tx is never failing.. always goes through and I always get ~5 BUSD. Is there any way to **make the transaction fail** if I don't get at least 10 BUSD? (I used BUSD just as example)

Thanks a lot.. hope it makes sense :/

SS for reference:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a failed transaction hash? Are you using the correct number of decimals?

Comment: No, all the transactions are going through and none fails. I used '10' for amountOutMin.. maybe this is wrong?..

Comment: Can you show a sample transaction where you expected the output to be above 10 busd but it was 5 instead?

Comment: Sure, I also added an img in the post for reference. 
tx: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x54f915a549baee329489d3135b076bf073cb144409fca6bff174135250375b31

I just want to know if I can make it fail if I don't get the desired amount.
Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when making the call you use

```
amountOutMin = 10
```

Now the [BUSD](https://bscscan.com/token/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56) token has 18 decimals. To indicate 10 USD you have to call with

```
amountOutMin = 10 * 10**18
```

Comment: Got it! I gave it a try with 10 followed by 18 zeros and when trying to send the transaction it suggests a ridiculous amount of BNB for gas. (0.38 BNB).
However, upon changing the suggested gas limit from 76mil to something normal (100K), the estimated gas fee became normal and once confirmed, the transaction failed. Now, does this finally mean that the transaction got reverted because I could not get the desired 10 BUSD? (Note that if I use amountOutMin '5' BUSD with 18 zeros, which is less than 0.01 BNB, the tx goes through without any problems). Thanks a lot for you time @Ismael!

Comment: @Marty The minimum output is a mechanism to prevent a bad trade. The frontends usually set it using the slippage percentage of the expected output. If slippage is 1% then if you expect 5 USD it will set it to 4.95.

Comment: For me the whole point of this little experiment is to find a safe way to buy as early as possible in a new token launches, without using the frontends. As an example, say I intend to buy $100 of token A, which launches at $1. I intend to pay as high as $2/token A, so I set amountOutMin to 50 (followed by 18 zeros). If the price of token A instantly goes to $3 by the time my tx is reached, will it fail (as I do not get my minimum of 50 tokens) or will it succeed and I get 33 tokens? Thank you!